# Most Popular Items from Library Sorting Not Working

Tags: web-part, sorting

When i click into the page of Most Popular items that has the sorting of recent and ever. But i click these two buttons that has no any response. i checked IE F12 debug mode that also has not any errors.

Any Idea?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Documents viewed in the Office Web App are recorded for Most Popular report

Apart from that you also need to enable usage data collection(central Admin ->Monitoring ->Configure Usage and Health data collection)

Also ensure Analytics related jobs and services are up and running..

For detailed information..you can check on links below

[Recent and ever are zero in most popular items page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4c070d79-32a3-4bba-893e-42325ccdf9f3/recent-and-ever-are-zero-in-most-popular-items-page?forum=sharepointgeneral)

[Most Popular Items from Library Sorting Not Working](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e7c511b1-66be-4480-bcf0-5b135ca99d96/most-popular-items-from-library-sorting-not-working?forum=sharepointgeneral)

[Most Popular Items not working for document libraries](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/71066e40-87cd-4a6b-88fd-d78daa1b858f/most-popular-items-not-working-for-document-libraries?forum=sharepointgeneral)